# Is there a way to check if value sent to variable is right type while it is already under that var?

Tags: c++, arguments

I couldn't find a way to check if the value that was passed into variable is right type.

For example: I have passed char into int variable and I would like to check if it is int inside int(?). I thought about checking if argument that was sent is in ascii table, but i don't find this as optimal solution. Some code:

```
Martice m('q');
```

when

```
Martice (int _arg) : pass(_arg) { allocation(); };
```

I know that I could use this method to check input:

```
if (std::cin.fail() == true) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
```

but my point is to check it later, after passing it as argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to distinguish between characters and integers, then you could use overloading of the `Martice` constructor. So you have one constructor taking an `int`, and one taking a `char`.

If you want to disallow passing of `char`, then you could mark the `char` overload as deleted:

```
explicit Martice(char) = delete;
```

If you want to allow it, but convert digit characters to numbers it's a little more complicated, as you must then use default-construction (if possible) and then convert the character and use assignment:

```
explicit Martice(char _arg) : Martice()  // Delegating to default constructor
{
    if (!std::isdigit(_arg))
    {
        // TODO: Not a digit, do something, perhaps throw an exception
    }
    else
    {
        pass = _arg - '0';  // Convert digit to number
        allocation();
    }
}
```

---

Note the use of `explicit` for the constructors. That will disallow implicit conversion from characters to `Martice` objects.

Comment: Could be useful to suggest `explicit` on these constructors as well.